# C++ Tree node recursion

Tags: c++

How does the recursion work for the function provided?

```
struct tree
{
    int value;
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
};

void recursion(tree* head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        recursion(head->left);
        cout << head->value << endl;
        recursion(head->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    tree* head;
    
    tree* newNode = new(struct tree);

    newNode->value = 2;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    head = newNode;

    newNode = new(struct tree);
    newNode->value = 1;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    head->left = newNode;

    newNode = new(struct tree);
    newNode->value = 3;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    head->right = newNode;

    recursion(head);

    return 0;

}
```

Traversing through the tree node with the recursion() function, during recursion(head->left) inside the function, when it finally hits NULL does the end of that state of recursion become 'head->value' and use the cout << head->value << endl; line of code to print 1? Vice versa for recursion(head->right)? I'm having a hard time understanding how exactly the last left node is being printed granted i'm only using cout for the head->value node.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? The best way for you to learn how to recursion works is to use your debugger to run the recursive function, one line at a time, see all the recursive calls as they happen.

Comment: The thing you're looking for is likely a debugger. Alternatively, you might add more logging.

Comment: Ahh okay I see it now with the debugger, but basically am I correct in the sense that when recursion(head->left) is finished (or hits NULL) the cout << head->value << endl; that the head variable "becomes" that furthest left node? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: When recursion is "finished", the the last call returns, and execution continues normally, with the next statement. The `head` variable does not "become" anything. Each function call has its own `head` variable, and it's what it always is.

Comment: Oh right, that makes so much more sense now, Thank you!! @SamVarshavchik, and for instance if the head->left actually had a right node, it would call that as well instead of "finishing"? I think what confused me was naming the recursion(tree* head) variable Head because it's not going to always be the top of the tree, its just a node

Comment: Well, yes printing the value of the node the function can't finish without a recursive call on the right node.

Comment: @Parker  `recursion` function with "null left" and "null right" are being called but it is jut not doing anything and returns immediately because it is entering with `head` as null. Having the variable in the `recursion` function with the name `head` seems to be a common thing. I I keep seen it. I prefer to call this `branch` because this is only head on the first call. But this is just a personal choice. Also, I would have named the function print, since it is more descriptive of what it is doing.

Comment: @guivi thank you! I definitely confused myself with the name 'head' thinking that it will only be the very top node of the tree but that's not the case, I now realize that when recursion() is called inside the function, I pass in head->left so the 'recursive' function's head is now at position 'head->left'

Answer (score 0):

Using a debugger makes it easier to learn how code is executed as it follows the exact execution order. This when threading is not taken into account.

Sometimes, with difficult patterns, it helps to just draw it on paper. It will make is very visible for what is going on.

The graph below starts with your first created struct with `newNode->value = 2;`

The green arrows show the order of execution.

`out 1`, `out 2` and `out 3` are the `head->value` in your function.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome thank you very much, I learn much more with visual approaches as well, it really helps.

Comment: Fixed the image.